# ASUS Laptop batter won't charge past ~60%

Tags: windows-10, battery, asus-laptop

My laptop is an ASUS N552VX bought 18 months ago. After less than 300 cycles my battery is reported as having lost more than 50% of its full capacity. Moreover, and that is the issue I am trying to fix, the Windows 10 tray bar battery indicator won't go past 60% while it used to go to 100% a couple of weeks ago, which makes little sense to me since the value to be displayed should not be affected by any potential loss in actual capacity.

Here is a [fresh report of my battery](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rr2o01kdvffu8i/battery_report.html?dl=0)

I am thus humbly asking for someone to:

1. Help me fix the "not above 60%" issue
2. Possibly help me diagnose if there is something totally wrong in my use of the laptop which would be responsible for the loss in capacity.

PS: Not using Insiders' builds.

Comment: In some recent Insider Fast Builds there have been battery reporting issues. Are you using these builds?

Comment: Nope, I am not. My Windows 10 build number reads 15063.483

Comment: Sounds like one of the cells in your battery has gone bad. Sorry but if that is the case you will need to replace it. Perhaps you can find someone with a compatible battery and test it in your laptop.

Comment: @Rick Brant: Thank you sir, how did you reach this conclusion? Is there a specific point in the battery report suggesting that a cell has died?

Comment: Laptop batteries consist of several series-parallel sets of cells. A "9 cell battery" will have three sets of cells, each set made of three cells in parallel, the  three sets in series for the usual laptop battery voltage of around 11 volts (3x3.7). When you lose a cell it drags down the others in its parallel set, and the usual result is a drop in capacity and "chargeability" that you're seeing.

Comment: @Rick Brant: Illuminating, thanks. So logic suggests that I should lose 30% plus what the non-defective yet worn-down 2 sets in series have lost already, bringing us close to the +50% I am seeing in the report, right?
Any clue if this scenario should be met with free battery pack change from the manufacturer (i.e. because the cells are dying "too fast")?

Comment: Sorry, no clue. You'll have to ask Asus.

Answer (score 1):

This is ASUS function for battery management. You can channge it from ASUS/ASUS battery health charging menu from start menu. There are 3 modes of charging - 60%/80%/100%. Lowest is for battery longest live, user should used it when his notebook is mostly pluged.

Comment: If possible I'd suggest to use a laptop that is mostly plugged in completely with the battery removed. The battery is best stored at around 50-60% of charge.

Comment: Explicitly, how does one change this setting?

Comment: For the love of God, I couldn't find any of these settings. It says you can manage that in customization settings, but impossible to find it.

Answer (score 1):

After 1 hour of searching, this option is now on the "MyAsus" App -> Customization

Answer (score 0):

Click the start key and type "ASUS Battery Health Charging" Click the icon and it should bring you to the page where you can change the maximum charge for your laptop.